# htacess: WP like rewrite not working for my PWA

Tags: .htaccess

I have a PWA hosted @ https://grassrootsapp.in/ and it's working great.

Now I would like rewrite all URLs like
http://grassrootsapp.in/n/5/thozhan/e/393/chennai--traffic-awareness-campaign

so they are served by index.html. Actual content for each URL will be handled by index.html (which is a PWA)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I just copied .htaccess from Wordpress, which has exactly same logic. With above .htaccess, my index.html is being served for the above link http://grassrootsapp.in/n/5/thozhan/e/393/chennai--traffic-awareness-campaign

But the problem is all resouces referred in index.html like,

```
build/vendor.js
build/main.js
```

are also served with contents of index.html rather than actual file. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" would seem to be that you are using relative URLs in your client-side HTML to these static resources. If your page URL is `https://example.com/n/5/thozhan/e/393/chennai--traffic-awareness-campaign` and you have a relative URL to a JavaScript file like `build/vendor.js` then the *browser* is going to request `https://example.com/n/5/thozhan/e/393/build/vendor.js` - which I suspect does not exist. Any requests for non-existent resources get rewritten to `index.php` (or is that `index.html`?) by your `.htaccess` directives.

Ideally, you need to change these relative URLs to be root-relative (starting with a slash, eg. `/build/vendor.js`) or even absolute (with a scheme + hostname). So that the browser will correctly resolve the URL.

Alternatively, you can include a `base` element in the `head` section of the document containing the absolute URL that all in-page relative URLs are relative to. For example:

```
<base href="https://example.com/index.html">
```

However, you should note that the `base` element is not without its caveats. Notably, if you are using in-page anchors using just fragment identifiers. As these will now be relative to the URL specified in the `base` element, not the URL of the current page.